# WIN10 or ADB: Show connected Android Devices

Tags: python, android, cmd, adb, device-manager

i am using Android Debugging Bridge (ADB) via Python (Win10) to access android device information.

**Problem:** 
- I am testing with lots of different devices

- I want to know whether there are devices that are connected, but with disabled debugging mode (like in the windows explorer or device manager, the Device is shown)
- Want to reach this by python or cmd

With adb i am getting the Information of "adb devices" => DUMxxxxx : device (or unauthorized) . 
But only devices with enabled Debugging mode are shown...

So is there a way to get to the same identifier (like serial number or device name) with both, adb and a python-windows-api with comparing them in addition?

In addition, is there a way to get the product name of a "device" shown in adb devices, if it is not authorized?

### **An Example:**

Huawei P30 lite, Samsung S20 and Honor 20 connected via USB.

Huawei P30 lite: 
- Debugging mode on, but not authorized via touch display
- ADB would show: DUMxxxx1 : unauthorized

Samsung S20: 
- Debugging mode on, authorized via touch display
- ADB would show: DUMxxxx2 : device

Honor 20: 
- Debugging mode off
- ADB would show:                  (None)

**Code output should be:**
"Huawei P30 lite is connected, but not authorized"

### "Honor 20 is connected, but debugging mode not activated."

I am wondering if anyone may help me with this?

Comment: Welcome to SO, I hope you find the answer to your question soon!